# CakePHPのSQLのCase文でカラム名の追加方法

Tags: cakephp

kbn、nameはカラム名なんですが、 `|| name` の部分が文字列として認識されテーブルのカラム名として認識してほしいのですが、どのように記述すればよいのでしょうか？

SQL文

```
select 
 case when kbn = '1' then '1' || name 
 else '2' 
 end username 
from user;
```

CakePHP

```
$username = $query->newExpr()->addCase(
                [$subquery->newExpr()->add(['kbn' => '1')],
                ["'1' || name" ,new IdentifierExpression('2')],
                ['string', 'string']
            );
```

Comment: 追加のSQLってなんでしょうか？

Comment: 記載方法が悪かったので訂正しました。
Case文の結果とカラム名を足した結果の記述方法が知りたいということです。

Comment: '1' || name   は何をしたい部分なんでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

'1', '2' となっている部分が外部入力値でなければ、newExprでSQLをそのまま書いてよいと思います。
（SQLインジェクションが発生しない前提）

```php
$expr = $query->newExpr("case when kbn = '1' then '1' || name else '2' end");
$query->select(['username' => $expr]);
```

外部入力の可能性があるなら、SQLインジェクションを考慮して値をバインドするようにメソッドで組立てます。

```php
$expr = $query->newExpr()->addCase(
    $query->newExpr()->eq('kbn', '1'),
    [
        $query->func()->concat(['1', $query->identifier('name')]),
        '2',
    ],
    ['string', 'string']
);
$query->select(['username' => $expr]);
```

`IdentifierExpression` は、テーブルのフィールド名などの識別子を指定する時に使用します。
`$query->identifier('field_name')` は、 `new IdentifierExpression('field_name')` のシノニムになります。

[式の中で識別子を使用する | クエリービルダー - 4.x](https://book.cakephp.org/4/ja/orm/query-builder.html#id12)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
1点質問なのですが「$query->newExpr()->or」ここの部分ですが何故orになるのでしょうか？

Comment: `||` に対応する関数がないので等価な`or`を使用しています。

Comment: || はSQLなので＋の意味です。紛らわしくて申し訳ありません。
new IdentifierExpressionは、それ以外の場合にしか使用できないのかと思っておりましたがそうではなかったのですね・・・。
意図した結果が取得できましたので、ありがとうございました。

Comment: DBMSがわからなかったのでMySQL前提でORと思ってました。PostgreSQLかOracleでしたか。

Comment: 文字列結合だとconcatを使用すればいいですね。回答のコードを書き換えておきました。